# AssertionError: Number of Block dimensions (1) must equal number of axes (2)

Tags: pandas

I am working on a classification problem and using the pandas library for the data analysis. When using the pd.Dataframe() function I am getting the above error. I am new to it and do not understand the meaning of this error. Below is my code

```
`from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import RandomizedPCA
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
img_dir = 'pics/'
pics = [img_dir+ f for f in os.listdir(img_dir)]
def extrct_labels(filename):

    n = len(filename)
    y = np.zeros(n,dtype = np.int32)

    for i,filename in enumerate(filename): 
        # If 'check' string is in file name assign '0'
        if 'check' in str(filename):
            y[i] = 0
        else:
            y[i] = 1
    return y
data = []
for pic in pics:
    img = imread(pic)
    img = img.flatten()
    data.append(img)

data = np.array(data)
pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=2)
X = pca.fit_transform(data)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x-1": X[:,0], "x-2": X[:,1], "label": np.where(y==1, "Driver's License", "Check")})
`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show a sample of your X array. That is causing the problem. If I generate X as `X = np.random.randn(n,2)`, and y as `y = np.random.binomial(1,0.65,10)`, I can create a DataFrame using your statement without problems.

Comment: looks like pca is expecting the variable 'data' to be 2-dimensional whereas it is 1

Comment: @Sword: In the question she says, "When using the `pd.Dataframe()` function I am getting the above error". I think PCA is working just fine.

Comment: Even I thought that X might be creating a problem but that is not the case: array([[  1.00671519e+03,  -7.88588076e+02],
       [  9.61090433e+02,   1.96901560e+03],
       [  5.24978639e+03,   1.41779807e+03],
       [  5.04534915e+03,  -1.89233296e+03],
       [  6.95240139e+03,   2.25431977e+03],
       [  3.80574842e+03,  -1.23160789e+03],
       ..., [  6.98498536e+03,   2.31864714e+03],
       [ -3.94030649e+03,  -3.39666330e+03]])

Comment: and the code without label argument is working fine                              df = pd.DataFrame({"x-1":X[:,0],"x-2":X[:,1]}) but when I am using         df = pd.DataFrame({"x-1": X[:,0], "x-2": X[:,1], "label": np.where(y==1, "Driver's License", "Check")}) its not working.                                           I want to get the data labeled and plot it accordingly.